# Use a wildcard as a directory level in PHP

Tags: php, directory, hierarchy, config

What is the best way to skip over a directory level in PHP using some kind of wildcard expression?

I have a config.php file that is unique to each child directory and I need to include it in the header of my page.

Example:

```
http://mysite.com/dir1/dir2/could-be-anything/config.php
http://mysite.com/dir1/dir2/something-different/config.php
http://mysite.com/dir1/dir2/different-again/config.php
```

What I want is to tell my main PHP page to include config.php when the name of it's parent directory may change?

Something like `<?php include("http://mysite.com/dir1/dir2/*/config.php"); ?>`

Comment: Should the subdir become the subdir of the url (e.g. could-be-anything)?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `glob` and a foreach to include each file that matches.

```
foreach (glob("path/*/config.php") as $config)
    include($config);
```

See the [man page on `glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) for more specifics.

Answer (score 1):

If the location is defined by dir1 and dir2 and the third one is simply a readable unkown, then you can accomplish it with a single expression:

```
include(current(glob("./dir1/dir2/*/config.php")));
```

<sub>Note: Loading an include script over `http://mysite/...` is not possible. HTTP provides no directory listings, and it wouldn't work because that config.php script would be parsed away in that case.</sub>